# Adding multiple TextView(s) in a LinearLayout causes stackOverflowError

Tags: android, view

I need to add multiple `TextViews` to a `LinearLayout`.

But the code is creating some kind of cyclic dependency which is causing `stackOverflowError`.

```
 LinearLayout tagsLayout;
 tagsLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager_item_tags);

  if (!tagsArrayList.isEmpty()) {
      TextView tagTitle = new TextView(context);
      tagTitle.setText("Tags: ");
      tagsLayout.addView(tagTitle, 0);
      TextView tagsTextView = new TextView(context);
      tagsTextView.setGravity(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
      tagsTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_tag);                            
      tagsTextView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorWhite));
      tagsTextView.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 0);

      for (Tags tags : tagsArrayList) {
          tagsTextView.setText(tags.getName());

         /*generating some kind of cyclic dependency*/

        if (tagsTextView.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) tagsTextView.getParent()).removeView(tagsTextView);
        }

        tagsLayout.addView(tagsTextView);
     }

  }
```

If I do not use `getParent().removeView()`
I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException you must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`
I need to display *tags* which varies in number so, I can't use **xml** to achieve the desired result.

Thanks for your help.

**StackTrace:**

```
  java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6081)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6082)


        android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4105)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:89)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: What's the stack trace when you get the stackOverflowError?

Comment: What about add your tagsTextView outside the for loop?

Comment: @Buddy I've added the stackTrace

Comment: @EdgarMarcoPolo I tried that already, doesn't solves the issue

Comment: You're adding the same `tagsTextView` object multiple times... create a new one for each tag.

Comment: @Buddy trying your suggestion. Will get back to you soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only creating one `TextView` changing the text multiple times then adding only a single `TextxView` to the parent layout.

All of the code to create it should be inside your loop

```
 for (Tags tags : tagsArrayList) {
    // create it here and add it
}
```

I'm not sure if this will solve the exception or not but it's what I think you are wanting to do.

The properties that won't change could be declared once outside of the loop then set inside the loop when you create it.

For example

```
int textColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorWhite)
```

then, inside your loop

```
tagsTextView.setTextColor(textColor);
```

Comment: It didn't solved the issue.
I am still getting the same StackTrace

Comment: tagsLayout is already initialized, I forgot to copy that line of code. Apologies

Comment: If you comment out that code, do you get the same exception?

Comment: It worked as you suggested. I was so tangled that i messed a for loop, didn't saw that until now. 
Thanks a lot for the help.